# More than one VPN connection on one client

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to be connected to more than one VPN connection? I tried it with a second operating system running on virtualbox, my host is connected to a VPN and my guest runs another connection. Which IP should am I be visible when I use the browser of my guest? Is it the IP of my host or my guest or do this connections run parallel because of the gateway and the routing table? Is a simpler solution without virtualbox possible?

Comment: To find out your IP, use websites like https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: In your setup, probably the second VPN in your VM goes through the first VPN on your host. The provider of the second VPN does not know your real public IP but only the public IP of the first VPN. This adds another level of security/stealthiness but also increases latency.

Answer (score 1):

At least in theory, you can have as many VPN connections as you want.
Sometimes there are some firewall / protocol limits, such that you cannot 
start a new vpn connection through another. Latency also increases fast
when you stack too many VPN connections.

It depends on the configured routes when you connect to a new VPN, 
whether the new VPN connection goes through existing ones or is completely
independent.